# Arch Linux: Despite ot static ip configuration I get a DHCP address

Tags: networking, dhcp, arch-arm

This is very strange to me. On my Raspberry Pi running the latest Arch Linux I disabled all the DHCP service on ETH0 and everything else DHCP:

```
rm /etc/dhcpcd.duid
pacman -R dhclient
pacman -R dhcpcd
```

And I defined static ETH via `/etc/netctl/ethernet-static`:

```
Description='A basic static ethernet connection'
Interface=eth0
Connection=ethernet
IP=static
Address=('10.0.1.30/24')
Gateway=('10.0.1.1')
DNS=('10.0.1.1')
```

And still, after the DHCP lease time, I loose the static IP and get a (different) DHCP address again. What am I missing here?

P.S.: It seems there's a bug in the bcm2708 device driver that triggers an USB disconnect (to which ETH bound). But anyway - if DHCP is disabled, why do I get a DHCP address?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing is that dhcpd and dhclient are not the way the raspberry pi gets its DHCP address on archlinuxarm... They used systemd-networkd because it is simpler and lighter. Just edit the file `/etc/systemd/network/eth0.network` as follows:

```
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
DHCP=no
```

or even as

```
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
DNS=10.0.1.1

[Address]
Address=10.0.1.30/24

[Route]
Gateway=10.0.1.1
```

and you get everything you need.

Before you ask: DHCP has been activated by default because you then you can SSH into it pretty easily without a spare screen and keyboard.

---

Just one thing. I hope you limited the range of possible addresses given by you DHCP server before that. Static addresses in a DHCP network is not always a good idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I just edited this config file and will see (and report), what happens. I actually had to limit the DHCP range, because I cannot split DHCP and static networks here for technical reasons. The DHCP address I got was from the defined range.

Comment: My problem is not solved completely. As the USB bug appears, it stops the network service. But I think, your answer was correct to my initial question, so I will mark it as such. I found some more details on switching from netcl to systemctl here: http://archlinuxarm.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=58&t=8045 The point is, you might have to disable one or more netctl services in order to do a clean switch.

Comment: The first part of this answer just solved this problem for me on the Beaglebone Black